# InApp Subscriptions or Google Wallet

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay

I have gone through most of the links here on stackoverflow and i have some doubts regarding InApp Subscriptions and Google Wallet.

What i know:

1. InApp Subscriptions basically allows a user to be able to subscribe to an app, say for example if it offers one year trial period, then once thats over, Google automatically handles the subscriptions then after.
2. Google Wallet, its a method that can be used to perform the purchase. **What i don't understand is, can i use this method in order to allow users to use the app for one year, and then make them pay for the next years?**

> Billing continues indefinitely at the interval and price specified for the subscription. At each subscription renewal, Google Play charges the user account automatically, then notifies the user of the charges afterward by email. For monthly and annual subscriptions, billing cycles will always match subscription cycles, based on the purchase date. (Seasonal subscriptions are charged annually, on the first day of the season.)

This is what happens in my app:
 1. A user logs in, and i get a date that probably keeps track of the billing cycle
 2. If the sessions expired, the user is asked to pay using the inApp Billing serivce
 3. Based on TrivailDriveApp Example, where we have the success log printed on subscription, we update the date of payment.

Some questions i have:

1. As per the quote from android, if the user is automatically subscribed to the service, and if a mail is sent to the user, does that mean that i would never be able to get a notification about the payment extension? How do i sync that with the server then?
2. Is my approach wrong in handling this kind of scenario? Or do i have to select a different method of handling app extensions?

P.S: There is no way of testing inapp subscriptions also. I wonder if i could do that without using real credit/debit card credentials.

**EDIT:**

I would also want to keep track of when the purchase or billing was done, if subscriptions are auto-renewed, then should i take up the purchase flow as an InApp Product instead of an InApp Subscription?

Please help.